# A general method for counting functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions, permutations

Let $A={x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5}$  $B={y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4}$
A function from A to B is defined such that $f(x_1)=y_1 $
$f(x_2)=y_2$

How many onto functions can be defined from A to B

I took 2 cases

1.${x_3,x_4,x_5}$ are not associated with either y1,y2

*Total cases*
*2×2×2 -2*

EXPLANATION:since each $x_r$ r=,3,4,5 has 2 choices and there are 2 cases where no element is associated with $y_3,y_4$

2. $x_r$ r=,3,4,5 is either associated with y1 or y2

*Total cases*
3×3×3- 15

EXPLANATION =since each $x_r$ r=,3,4,5 has 3 choices and there are 15 cases where no element is associated with $y_3,y_4$

I want to know is there a more general approach which can be applied when no. Of elements involved are more
This question is same but has one answer and specifically emphasizes on finding op's mistake my question has a different demand

[Find number of onto functions if $f(x_1)=y_1$ and $f(x_2)=y_2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2242839/731426)